# Ajax file Upload giving the undefined index file from the php side

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've tried everything i came across and i am sure there is something i dont have in the code .Please i need some help thks.
This is the html which is a form with one input which should receive the file

```
<div id="Posts">
       <h1 style="text-align: center;color: red;">SERVICES</h1>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color:red;">***</span> please ensure to look at the definitions of every field... <span style="color:red;">***</span></p>
     <form id="promo_imgs"  enctype="multipart/formdata">
       <h5 style="text-align: center;"> About the Services You offer</h5><hr style="width: 30%; border:0.5px dashed red;">
  <div id="imgpr" class="imgpromo" style="max-width: 40%; min-height: 60px;border:dashed 0.5px;">
            <label for="promotion" class="btn btn-primary">
              Select an Image
            </label> 
             <img  src="" alt="" width="100%" style="max-height: 250px;" id="img">
     <input type="file" name="promo0" accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg" id="promotion" style="display:none;">
</div>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="serv_upload" name="serv_upload">Upload</button>
     </form><span id="ajax">
     <!--upload an image -->
      </span>
```

then this is the jquery part of it which should preview the image (which works) and then upload the image(which goes successfully to return an undefined index file error)

```
   /* to preview before upload service images*/
$(document).on('change',"#promotion",function(){ 
  var link =URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    console.log(link);
  var $this=$(this);
    $("#img").slideDown("fast").attr('src',link);
 $("#serv_upload").slideDown("slow");
      }); 
/* to upload service images*/
$(document).on('click',"#serv_upload",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#ajax").html("Uploading...");


var files = $('#promotion').val(e.target.files);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i]; 
      var formdata= new FormData();
   formdata.append('file',file); 
    $("#ajax").append(file.name);  
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"aboutinsert.php",
        data:{formdata:formdata},
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        cache:false,
        success: function(data){
          $("#ajax").html(data);
        }
      });
    } 
         });
```

Finally the php part

```
 $dir="img/portfolio" ;


$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $path = $dir.basename($file);
   $ext= pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $extensions = array("JPG","jpg","jpeg","png");
  $exts=strtolower($ext);
  if (!in_array($exts, $extensions)) {
    # code...
    echo "sorry you donot have the right file format";
  }
  elseif ($_FILES['file']['size']>2000000) {
    # code...
    echo "your file is larger than 2mb";
  }
  elseif (file_exists($path)) {
    # code...
    echo "sorry a file already exists with this name change the name and try again";
  }
  else{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        # code...
        echo  basename($_FILES['file']['name']). "upload success";
    }
    else{
        echo "file Upload failed";
    }
  }
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: yes my jquery lib is added correctly and no other unexpected jquery issues and i am running the code on my local xampp server

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some random names being used in the `$_FILES` array in your PHP code. You use:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

and then

```
 elseif ($_FILES['promo0']['size']>2000000) {
```

and finally

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
```

Which is it? If you're not certain, you could `var_dump($_FILES);` and see what you have.

Comment: yeah am sorry you saw that its a mistake but even at that the problem is not solved because actually the error comes from the second line of the code  and it does not go right through

Comment: i have done it ,but there is no change this is the error it gives. Undefined index: file on line 3